# Hammer.js swipe support for 1 and/or 2 fingers

Tags: angular, touch, swipe, hammer.js

I'm using Hammer.js with Angular 5 to support swipping with both mouse and touch. The problem is that the touch action should be done with two fingers instead of one.

Is it possible to support both 1 and 2 pointers in Hammer.js for swipping (left and right)?

Ideally I'd also want to distinguish between mouse and touch since the "mouse" event returns maxPointers: 1 (always?).

Comment: See if his helps https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/549?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Unfortunately the property dragMaxTouches didn't make it to version 2.0 of the library. It's only in 1.1. Thanks though!

Comment: And what about the other code that someone has posted on the issue? Does that work somehow now also?

Comment: Unfortunately using the pinch recognizer conflicts with vertical scrolling on the element. Since the swiping movement is used in tabs within a child element, if the pinch recognizer is enabled you cannot scroll inside this child element or its children. Not sure if this is a bug in hammer.js

Comment: @TarunLalwani Reply above, not sure if you got a notification.

Comment: Yeah I read that, just didn't have further inputs to contribute to

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thanks for bringing this to my attention at least. Using "pinchmove" does what I want but still scrolling doesn't work... bummer

Comment: Probably you can put some workaround to that by figuring out the events, not sure not a hammer.js user